# Lite version of a full app in Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, storyboard, target

I have an app called "Gatti" in the Apple Store. I'm trying to submit a new version called Gatti Lite but i'm very confused. In my app (created using storyboard) i've a scrollView with a lot of buttons. In the lite version i want to reduce the number of this buttons (then functions). I've tryied to duplicate targets but i have a lot of unsolved questions:

1. i've to create a new storyboard? Can i put this new storyboard like the main for the lite version?
2. Can I update, with an in-app purchase button, from lite version (removed) to the full version?
3. Does exist a Walktrought to do this operation in Xcode 4 (buil a lite version)?
4. How can I create two separate apps in the apple store? I want to have 2 different icon, description,...in the itunesconnect. Is it possible? (in the lite version i can't use the full version's description.

Thank You guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write and distribute another version of your application (lite) at App Store then you should have another project in xCode, create new storyboard and bring needed code from full version. Two projects, two apps.

As I know you can't replace your app to another app with in-app button (this upgrade from lite version to full is de facto replacing one app to another)

*How to publish new app:*

Create new app `Bundle ID` here https://developer.apple.com/certificates/index.action

and then add new application via iTunesConnect https://itunesconnect.apple.com

You will have two apps on AppStore with different meta and icons

There's similar question on StackOverFlow about connecting lite and full versions [Connecting the LITE Version to the FULL Version on App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096769/connecting-the-lite-version-to-the-full-version-on-app-store)

You can look there

Comment: Ah ok, i'm doing this "method", building a new app. A lot of people release a version full, limited in the lite, but i don't know how to separate this two apps in the store! :) OFF TOPIC: how can i increase my reputation on stack overflow? tnk you

Comment: It's no problem with separating - just publish lite version like it is just another app. If you want to connect lite and full version - so I updated my post by adding a link to similar question. About reputation: ask questions, try to answer, accept answers - so just be active :)

Comment: Thank you!! :) I try to be active answering 2-3 question/day..but with little progress!! :) tnk you !! :)